# Error when trying to display parent name using acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-tree

I am using the acts as tree gem to create a `Category` model:

```
  1 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   include ActsAsTree
  3   attr_accessible :name
  4 
  5   acts_as_tree order: "name"
  6 end
```

In one of my views, I am trying to display the category's parent's name:

```
 12 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
 13   <tr>
 14     <td><%= category.name %></td>
 15     <td><%= category.parent.name %></td>
 16     <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
 17     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
 18     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '
 19   </tr>
 20 <% end %>
```

However, I am getting an error when accessing the view:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I can, however, display `category.parent_id` successfully.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dirty data in your database. you are getting `nil` when you call `category.parent` and when you call `name` method on `category.parent` you are actually calling `name` method on `nil` and hence it is giving an error `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`

This happens when you have data like following

```
id  name      parent_id
2   child1     1     
3   child2     1
```

Now i have above two data in my table, here you can see `parent` for both the record is `1`, so there must be have a record with id `1`.

```
<%
   child = Model.find 2
   child.parent_id #This gives you `1`
   child.parent #This gives you `nil`
   child.parent.name #This gives you error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
 %>
```

Comment: I don't think so... When calling child.parent I get the parent category instance: `#<Category:0x007fccf2272a10>`

Comment: You are iterating loop over `@categories` so if any category having dirty parent it will throw error.....i am not saying all the data is dirty but single record can raise a error..........change `<%= category.parent.name %>` to `<%= category.parent ? category.parent.name : category.parent_id %>` to check the dirty data

Comment: You're right. I think it has to do with the fact that the root category does not have a parent. But what can I do about this?

Comment: I think `<%= category.parent.name if category.parent %>` will solve a problem. For a root category it will display nothing.